# How do I remove or delete a JWT token with JWTAuth laravel package?

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

I am building a laravel 5/angular app and I am using [JWTAuth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) to manage my tokens. Does anyone know how to remove or delete a token? I want to use it for testing, but also for log out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the explanation how to do "logout" with JWT. It is not basically a logout but it is a "by the book" explanation how to work with it.

https://youtu.be/eWUkxzyB1Rk?t=7m49s

Comment: For example in Angular you can remove it form client-side and it will work. On backend you do not need to "logout from API". Here is the function:

delete $localStorage.token;

For complete case refer to this: http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs

Comment: that's the way I've been doing it. I wasn't sure if it was safe.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using JWTAuth version 0.4 or above you can use when you log out

```
JWTAuth::setToken($token)->invalidate();
```

It will basically put that token in blacklist until it expires.

You can get full details [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/18)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMHO. You can remove the token client-side but the token is technically still valid as far as the server is concerned, so if someone captured it, they could still use it. It's better to hit a route on the server to blacklist the token and on success remove it from the client side cache.

Comment: This is the only working way as even in version 1.0.2

Comment: How to intercept the token from the $request?